# Using CakePHP to build applications that deal with large data-sets?

Tags: datatables, cakephp-2.0, large-data

I am using Datatables JQuery plugin 1.9 with CakePHP 2.4.

My application is an online Database interface. The database is not relatively huge. We have only 26,000 records. However, I found out that even with recursive = -1, and the use of "Containable" behavior, CakePHP is still limited to find 5000 rows only, before I get a memory exhausted error, and it even takes 5 minutes to load, in the view!

Of course, using the LIMIT option was just experimental as I need to list/paginate/search through the entire database records.

My question is, have anyone built a CakePHP application that dealt with similar number of rows or larger?? How did you do it? Any detailed documentation reference about your approach would be greatly appreciated.

I've been looking for a week for setting up the server-side processing of Datatables in CakePHP and none of the solutions/plugins suggested out there worked (e.g. cnizzdotcom's). Increasing the memory limit (up to 1 GB!) didn't help much too.

Unfortunately, if this limitation continues this will be our last time using CakePHP. But for now, it's very critical to find a solution of the problem.

Comment: 26000 at once in a view is quite a lot, why do you choose not to use the paginator component/helper for this (since you mention you need to list/paginate/search)?

Comment: debugging shows the problem is at the find() statement. Do you think replacing the Datatables plugin with the cakephp paginator will change how find() fetches the data??

Comment: Not replacing, just thinking a bit more how to handle data. For example, if you are doing a `find('all')` with the sole purpose of displaying a simple list to the user (and implement pagination yourself after getting the 26000 records), then is just better to use the Paginator and let cake worry about everything else. If, on the other hand, you want to use the 26000 records on the controller and process them and do stuff with them, try to add a lot of conditions to not fetch *everything*. If you just absolutely need all records, share the code you are using so we can help you optimize.

Comment: Nunser, our find() statements are too optimized to do any further possible optimization. There is no find-inside-loop, nor nested for-loops, find() use recursive = -1, "containable" behavior, specified "fields". And yes, we need to process those ~26000 records in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you really need to display your 26k items at once on your datatables??

I'd change it and use an ajax pagination. You could still keep your datatables pagination and make an async request to cakephp (cake should return a json), in this request you'll need to pass the `limit` and the `page` (you could also pass the `sort` and `direction`) as parameters

- Search the datatable's doc for ajax sources
- create a view for this ajax
- in this view create paginate your items using the "page", "limit", "sort" and "direction" parameters passed to the view (via GET probablly)
- this view should return a json in a format that datatables could understand

But if you really need to display the 26k at once.. then ignore this answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: The entire database doesn't need to be displayed at once. Being available to search/paginate through is good enough. I never done your way, do you have a good documentation/tutorial/example you can refer me to? Thanks

Comment: ahhhh :P I'll try to search.. but it's a mix of different tutorials.. i'll try to gather them